# How to force re-validation of a value bound to custom element in aureliajs?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Let's say I have this custom element:

```
<div validation-errors.bind="form.imageDataErrors">
    <imagepicker image-data.two-way="form.model.imageData & validate" />
</div>
```

And a form class defined (approximately) like this:

```
export class ImageForm {
    constructor() {
        this.imageData = null;

        ValidationRules
            .ensure("imageData")
                .required()
            .on(this);
    }
}
```

Now, when user selects an image, I do this:

```
export class ImagePicker {
    @bindable imageData;

    onImageChange(data) {
        this.imageData = data;
    }
}
```

If I validate before user selects an image, then an error message is displayed. If I then select an image and validate again, the error doesn't disappear even though this time `imageData` is set. So how to force the validation engine revalidate this property?

**EDIT**

I found `validateBinding` method of `ValidationController` which I could use, but I don't know how to get the underlying binding for a property.